# launch a vncviewer process inside a form in c# winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm tryign to launch a vncviewer process inside a form in winforms app.

I dont' see any errors or exceptions, but the process launches outside the winforms. I'm not able to contain it inside my form.
Here is what I've tried. I debugged and noticed that the setparent function didnt change the window handle to my form.

```
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

 info.Arguments = hostIP;
 info.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe";
 info.UseShellExecute = true;
 info.CreateNoWindow = true;
 info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
 Process pDocked = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe");
 DictionaryClass.hostVNCName = pDocked.ProcessName;
 pDocked.WaitForInputIdle();
 appwin = pDocked.MainWindowHandle;              
 SetParent(appwin, this.Handle);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have understood your problem correctly, you want to display an external application in one of your application interfaces. If this is your purpose, you can simply call the **DLL** library located in the system and call the **SetParent** function as shown below:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

**Note**: You may get an error message with "DllImport". Just include the following:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Then add the code below in this way:

```
Process pDocked = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC 
Viewer\vncviewer.exe");
pDocked.WaitForInputIdle();
while (pDocked.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    pDocked.Refresh();
}
SetParent(pDocked.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
```